# fatal error #1035: Can't find include file "stdafx.h"

Tags: c, fatal-error, stdafx.h

I've started using **Pelles C compiler** as Microsoft Visual Studio won't work on my laptop. So, whenever I debug the following program, I get the "**fatal error #1035: Can't find include file "stdafx.h"**. What's wrong here and what should I do to fix it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "math.h"

int_tmain()

{
float mu=0, var=0, std;
float x[20]={84, 63, 21, 78, 82, 19, 83, 47, 23, 78, 54, 60, 91, 23, 29, 48, 37, 26};
int i, n=20;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    mu+=x[i];

    mu/=n;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    var+=(x[i]-mu)*(x[i]-mu)

    var/=n;
    std=sqrt(var);

printf("\nAverage=%f\t Variance=%f\t STDEV=%f\n", mu, var, std);

getch();
return 0;
```

Comment: `int_tmain`? Interesting funtion, what's it for? As a side-note, forget `TCHAR` ever existed, aside from writing and reading documentation, unless you are porting an ancient app.

Comment: You're not getting that error when you *debug*. You're getting it when you *compile*, likely because there is no such file in your include path (and probably isn't even needed for this to begin with, depending on your project configuration).

Comment: remove `#include "stdafx.h"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY tried removing it, got around 20 or 30 errors :/

Comment: @WhozCraig I haven't studied the part concerning my program in my course yet, so I have no idea what to write or what not to write. I'm just writing what my professor explained to us.

Comment: `stdafx.h` is a so-called precompiled header in Visual Studio. It's not available, so just delete this line. And yes, you'll get a bunch of errors. That's actually what should happen. Because there is a bunch of errors in your code :)

Comment: For standard headers, use, for example, `#include <stdio.h>`, not `#include "stdio.h"`.  The latter might work, but the `<>` form is correct.

Comment: @FreeNickname Okay. Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @KeithThompson tried both, still got the same result, no difference at all.

Comment: @ZeinaBadawy: I didn't mean to imply that that was the solution to your problem (that's why I posted it as a comment, not as an answer). It's just something else you should fix.

Comment: @KeithThompson my bad, I'm new here so I don't really know how it goes around. Thanks a lot anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    float mu=0, var=0, std;
    float x[20]={84, 63, 21, 78, 82, 19, 83, 47, 23, 78, 54, 60, 91, 23, 29, 48, 37, 26};
    int i, n=20;// n=18 ?

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        mu+=x[i];

    mu/=n;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        var+=(x[i]-mu)*(x[i]-mu);//<- you have forgotten the semicolon.

    var/=n;
    std=sqrt(var);

    printf("\nAverage=%f\t Variance=%f\t STDEV=%f\n", mu, var, std);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ZeinaBadawy [**See here**](http://ideone.com/gGQPJo). This will at least get to the point where it runs.  There are still logic errors, but this will get you past your current error, and should be accepted as the correct answer. (+1, btw, blue).

Comment: @ZeinaBadawy _Got 27 errors_ compile possible environment has been set correctly?